# How to replace fragment onclick of button inside if condition true?

Tags: java, android

fragment replacement not working if i put if condition in below code..

```
       _doneButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View _view) {


          Name(no.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
         if(loginsucess){


         android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.content, mainFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: What is the condition??

Comment: if(loginsucees){}

Comment: Check the answer i posted

Comment: Why don't you add that if statement to your code?

Comment: _doneButton.setEnabled(loginsucees);

Comment: @Kingraj if you reject my edit, then please format your code yourself. thank you. It's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
_doneButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View _view) {

if(true){

Name(no.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());


android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.content, mainFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answers rather than dumping code

Comment: this is not correct way..without getting name and password before only writing if condition ha?

Comment: wait u need condition for if the user entered pass and username right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(loginsucees){
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.content, mainFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
}
else {
//Do Nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_doneButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
     public void onClick(View _view) {
if(loginsucees){
 Name(no.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString());
  FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
  MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
  ft.replace(R.id.content, mainFragment,"main_fragment");
  ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
  }
}
});
```